# Capturing the click event on suggestion and intercepting the text on the soft keyboard android

Tags: android

Problem: In soft keyboard settings, there is a toolbar option, if we turn it on, it will give you some suggestions, for example, if a copied something, it will start appearing on the top of keyboard(marked red in the screen shot), if the user clicks that suggestion, it will be pasted on the edit text which have the focus.

Things i have tried.

- **override autofill method (not working, not called).**
- **added text watcher, beforeTextChanged is called and the editable text is empty.**
- **added the OnKeyListener (not working, not called).**
- **added the onTextContextMenuItem (not working, not called).**
- **Read bunch of questions on Stackoverflow but no question/answer is helping.**

here is the screen shot:
[image]

PS: I am not sure how can i capture this click, and intercept the text, problem is that I am using the custom view for OTP, and when user click that suggestion, only first box is filled with the first character because we have max length equals to 1. I want to capture that text and fill it in my view accordingly. Any help is appreciated.

I have checked the following documents

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste

Comment: Did you got any solution for this??

Comment: No. I tried many solution, but still nothing is working for me.

Comment: unfortunately, till now no.